# How to invoke built-in "Edit" and "Add" functionality in UIToolbar custom buttons

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitoolbar

I have added uitoolbar in uinavigationcontroller using IB (by selecting the check box - "show toolbar"). I used IB since this was easy to add flexible spacing bar buttons (I did not want to deal with spacing code programmatically). 
My issue is that I want to invoke the built-in edit and add functionality for the 2 toolbar buttons I added. I know that in the navigation bar I can use the following code and it will invoke this functionality

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
```

Above code takes care of the "Edit view", where the table view items are shown with a delete button next to them.

How can I achieve the same for the buttons that I added to the toolbar? I am using Xcode 4. Please point me to some code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(callEdit)];
```

In callEdit method.

```
-(void)callEdit {
     [self.tableView setEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer @iPhoneiPadDev. But if I do this wouldn't it set the buttons on Navigation Bar, rather than on the Toolbar? Also, I wanted the buttons on my toolbar to be placed on the right and left corners, which I could not achieve programmatically, hence I used IB (flexible space bar button item). How do I use the following statement on a button I created in IB - 'code' [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(callEdit)]; 'code'. Wouldn't the "alloc" stmt give me error since it is already created in IB?

Comment: Can someone please help me with this??

Comment: Hi @iPhoneiPadDev I was able to get the Edit and Add buttons to be displayed. But how do I implement the "callEdit" method, that you mentioned above. I am not able to figure out what is "tblView" in your answer above. I have a navigation based application and my tableviewcontroller is called RootViewController. Should I create a IBOutlet for my RootViewController? Please let me know